# Can Python console output be passed via html/css for styling/app display?

Tags: python, html, css, output

The following code prints a semi-styled Python output in the console:

```py
print("\x1b[1;34;50mKINdred Gifting\x1b[0m\n\nby\n\x1b[1;35;50mCouv's Corner\x1b[0m")
```

However, this is only a primitive styling compared to what I am looking for.
I am developing an app using python and the features included in the replit package:

```
pip install replit
```

and its database. I plan to switch to MySQL later on, but that is beside the point. Is it possible to style the code "print('XYX')" using html so that instead of being sent to the console as

> XYZ

it will be sent to an html/css destination as a variable where it can be styled and printed on a page like a webpage, ***XYZ***?

Comment: You could drop that in a text file somewhere that you can then read.

Comment: @tralph3
I have never eally used pygame, but could Pygame solve my problem?